# How to stop user to not access my action in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have some methods in my Controller like this

```
 public void Audittrail()
        {
            try
            {
                AUDITTRAIL audittrail = new AUDITTRAIL();
                audittrail.PROGNAME = "PrimaryMarket";
                audittrail.PROGOPTION = Convert.ToString(Session["PROGOPTION"]);
                audittrail.IOTIME = DateTime.Now;
                audittrail.LOGUSER = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["UserId"]);
                audittrail.IPSMSDATE = db.DTTRACKs.Max(z => z.CURRDATE);
                db.AUDITTRAILs.Add(audittrail);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionLogging.SendErrorToText(e);
                Response.Redirect("/Account/Error/");
            }
        }
```

My controller name is Customer
If User enter url like this 
http://localhost:49537/Customer/AudiTrail
this action gets Invoked,
So how do i stop this?
Using MVC5

Comment: Use Authorize attribute...
for more info
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Is there a reason the method is in the controller (and is public) if your don't want to to be mapped as a route?

Comment: Yes I am using Authorize attribute, but i am talking about that if user is authorize and he/she enter this url then this action gets invoked

Comment: yes for some reasons it is in controller@Esko

Comment: if user is authorized to call that action then he/she can access from url nothing wrong in it

Comment: I just want to make that action not acces by authorize user

Comment: Why iam getting downvote?

Comment: I think, you should reword your question. Your question is not clear. Controller actions are designed to be invoked this way, but you want to prevent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[HttpPost]` attribute. This prevent accessing this method by just entering its url in the browser. In your code you should call it with POST.

Use GET for methods that just return something; use POST for methods that update something.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an action filter for this,i have created 'CheckOwnerActionFilter':

```
public class CheckOwnerActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
 {    
   AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext();
   void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext  filterContext)
    {
     int userId = AppUserManager.GetUserId();
     var userEntity = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(t => t.UserId == userId);
     if (userEntity != null)
     {
      //Its means authorized
     }
     else
     {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/unauthorize/index");
     }
   }
 }
```

And after creating this you can add it on your controller's method,like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[CheckOwnerActionFilter]
 public void Audittrail()
 {

 }
```

After this as you will request this method it will first go in action filter 'CheckOwnerActionFilter', there you can check for authorisation by userid or some other parameter you want.
It will work good and this is standard format too for these kind of issues.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a new function to check if the current user is allowed to go through this or not:

```
 public void Audittrail()
    {
        if(isCurrentUserAuthorized())
        {
            try
            {
                AUDITTRAIL audittrail = new AUDITTRAIL();
                audittrail.PROGNAME = "PrimaryMarket";
                audittrail.PROGOPTION = Convert.ToString(Session["PROGOPTION"]);
                audittrail.IOTIME = DateTime.Now;
                audittrail.LOGUSER = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["UserId"]);
                audittrail.IPSMSDATE = db.DTTRACKs.Max(z => z.CURRDATE);
                db.AUDITTRAILs.Add(audittrail);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionLogging.SendErrorToText(e);
                Response.Redirect("/Account/Error/");
            }
        }
        else
           Response.Redirect("/Account/Default/");

     }
```